# Elixir mix compilation priority

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

Is is possible to specify compilation priority for modules? Lets say I have two files a.ex and b.ex and I want to compile b.ex first while using mix compile. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4):

The [require](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#require/2) special form is probably what you need.

Comment: So, if i do require b.ex in a.ex will it guarantee that b.ex will get compile first?

Comment: It works on the module level, not the file level. From module Bar, you can require Foo, which will guarantee that Foo is compiled first. If you have those modules in separate files, it will still work.